# Wrapping php code between opening and closing shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using shortcodes for a toggle element and I would like to put the output for the following code inside this toggle element.

```
<?php
function myget_info(){ 
echo '123';} ?>
```

The code i am using for the toggle and my function is

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[vc_toggle title="Toggle title"]' . myget_info() . '[/vc_toggle]' ); ?>
```

However when I use the above, the output from my function, appears on top of my toggle rather than inside my toggle.

Comment: maybe this is what you need https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-shortcode/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/evalphp/

Comment: @NikosM., i prefer not to use plugins and i want to use this code in my template file

Comment: copy the code from the plugin in your `functions.php`, its the same

Comment: @NikosM. any way of putting my php function into the shortcode?

Comment: Please don't install any plugin that allows you to execute arbitrary code from the WP editor. It is a terrible practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you're outputting the value of `myget_info()` immediately instead of returning it so it can be used inside `do_shortcode()`.

Change:

```
function myget_info() {
    echo '123';
}
```

To:

```
function myget_info() {
    return '123';
}
```